# Firebase realtime database is not getting updated

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to make a simple form, and putting the user input data into firebase realtime database.

below is my code

Form.js:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { db } from "../firebase";

const Form = () => {
    const [name, setName] = useState("");
    const [location, setLocation] = useState("");

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        db.collection('form').add({
            name: name,
            location: location,
        })
        .then(() => {
            console.log("Form is submitted");
        }).catch(error => {
            alert(error.message);
        });

        setName("");
        setLocation("");
    };
    return (
        <form className="form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <h1>Black eye Form</h1>
            <label>Name</label>
            <input placeholder="name" value={name} onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)} />
            <label>Location</label>
            <input placeholder="location" value={location} onChange={(e) => setLocation(e.target.value)} />
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    );
}

export default Form;
```

firebase.js:

```
import firebase from "firebase";

var firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  authDomain: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  databaseURL: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  projectId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  storageBucket: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  messagingSenderId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  appId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
})
var db = firebaseApp.firestore();
export { db };
```

I have installed firebase in my terminal using `npm install -s firebase`

But my firebase realtime database is not getting updated.
Also I am not getting `"Form is submitted"` message in my console.log when I submit the form.

**EDIT: My code works when I use Cloud Firestore, but it's not working on Realtime Database. Is there something wrong with my code? or there is something which I am doing is only making it possible to update the cloud firestore and not realtime database**

Comment: Did you set the rules to allow read and write in the realtime database dashboard?

Comment: Did you check the `console`, like can you add if you get any noticeable errors and your code says `console.log("Form is submitted")` when the form data is added into the `db`. Check if that statement is getting logged or not when you submit your form.

Comment: @JamesMcGlone yes. I am using test mode, which I think gives the ability to read and write in database

Comment: @GayatriDipali I am not getting my console message too.

Comment: Please edit the question to show the code that isn't working the way you expect.  If RTDB is not working, then show the code for RTDB, not Firestore.  They do not have the same APIs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have copy pasted your code to codesandbox and tried it and it worked, the screen shot of firestore:

[image: proof]

And the code sandbox console pic:
[image: proof2]

Then there is only one chance that maybe you have messed up your imports like ../firebase

Comment: did you check your imports

Comment: if my solution worked for you consider accepting my answer

Comment: Yes, it works if I use cloud firestore, but its not working if I use realtime database. Is there any particular reason for that??

Comment: Yeah because in your `firebase.js` file you have coded this :                                          
 ``var db = firebaseApp.firestore();
 `` so if you want to use realtime database you will have to do the particular implementation not by intialising firestore